# Determine the area limited by curves: $f(x)=2x^3-3x^2+9x$ and $g(x)=x^3-2x^2-3x$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Determine the area limited by curves:

$$f(x)=2x^3-3x^2+9x   \\
 g(x)=x^3-2x^2-3x$$

The correctly answer is: 25, How can I find it?

Comment: Could you clarify the question? We usually talk about area of regions, not of functions.  Are you looking for the area of some region that is bounded by the graphs of those functions?

Comment: Sorry, the correctly question is: Determine the limited area by curves f(x)=2x^3−3x^2+9x and g(x)=x^3−2x^2−3x

Comment: @Alfredo please edit your question accordingly

Comment: The correctly answer is: 25. But how can I find it?

Comment: You need more information. $f$ and $g$ do not enclose any bounded area.

Comment: That is exactly the question I've gotten in my test.

Comment: You need the "and the lines $x=a$ and $x=b$" part. @copper.hat is right.

Comment: maybe he's being asked to give the anti-derivatives evaluated at fixed $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the limits of the interval are given $a<b \in\mathbb{R}$, the fundamental theorem of calculus says that the "area" below the curve $f(x)$, and between $a$ and $b$ equals to $F(b)-F(a)$ where $F'(x)=f(x)$, $\forall x\in[a,b]$ (in case that such $F$ exists). Gladly, our $f$ & $g$ are polynomials and very easy to find an anti-derivative to (=indefinite integral).

So, we can find the anti-derivatives for $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ and evaluate the difference at $a$, $b$. If we let $S$ to be the area below $f(x)$ and above $g(x)$ we need to calculate the area below $f(x)$ and above the $X$ axis minus the area below $g(x)$ above the $X$ axis:
$$S = F(x)-G(x)|_{x=a}^{x=b}$$

Do you know what's the anti-derivative of a Polynomial?

Comment: Thanks @Amihai Zivan, Could you explain a little bit about anti-derifate of a Polynomial?

Comment: Notice that $\int f(x)+g(x) =\int f(x)+ \int g(x) $ so, you can integrate every "monic" by itself. Now, let $a\in\mathbb{R}$,  $(a\cdot x^n)' = a\cdot n \cdot x^{n-1} \Rightarrow \int a\cdot x^{n-1} = a\frac{x^n}{n}$.